# How to calculate 3 month active users

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, distinct

I have a table that contains an orderId, a timestamp and a customerId, like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testdata;

CREATE TABLE testdata (
`orderId` int,
`createdOn` datetime(6),
`customerId` int,
PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`)
);


INSERT INTO testdata (orderId, createdOn, customerId) VALUES

('1000001','2020-01-01 17:08:41.460000','101'),
('1000002','2020-01-02 18:01:00.180000','102'),
('1000003','2020-01-03 12:26:02.460000','103'),
('1000004','2020-01-04 13:32:42.610000','104'),
('1000005','2020-01-05 20:21:28.540000','101'),
('1000006','2020-01-06 11:54:20.530000','102'),

('1000007','2020-02-01 20:54:42.470000','102'),
('1000008','2020-02-02 10:21:29.470000','102'),
('1000009','2020-02-03 16:22:23.880000','102'),
('1000010','2020-02-04 16:22:23.880000','103'),
('1000011','2020-02-05 17:08:41.460000','103'),
('1000012','2020-02-06 18:01:00.180000','103'),

('1000013','2020-03-01 12:26:02.460000','102'),
('1000014','2020-03-02 13:32:42.610000','102'),
('1000015','2020-03-03 20:21:28.540000','103'),
('1000016','2020-03-04 11:54:20.530000','103'),
('1000017','2020-03-05 20:54:42.470000','104'),
('1000018','2020-03-06 10:21:29.470000','104'),

('1000019','2020-04-01 16:22:23.880000','103'),
('1000020','2020-04-02 16:22:23.880000','103'),
('1000021','2020-04-03 17:08:41.460000','103'),
('1000022','2020-04-04 18:01:00.180000','104'),
('1000023','2020-04-05 12:26:02.460000','104'),
('1000024','2020-04-06 13:32:42.610000','104'),

('1000025','2020-05-01 20:21:28.540000','103'),
('1000026','2020-05-02 11:54:20.530000','103'),
('1000027','2020-05-03 20:54:42.470000','104'),
('1000028','2020-05-04 10:21:29.470000','104'),
('1000029','2020-05-05 16:22:23.880000','105'),
('1000030','2020-05-06 16:22:23.880000','105'),

('1000031','2020-05-01 20:21:28.540000','104'),
('1000032','2020-05-02 11:54:20.530000','104'),
('1000033','2020-05-03 20:54:42.470000','104'),
('1000034','2020-05-04 10:21:29.470000','105'),
('1000035','2020-05-05 16:22:23.880000','105'),
('1000036','2020-05-06 16:22:23.880000','105')
;
```

Now I want to calculate for each month the number of customers that have been active (i.e., have an order) within the last 3 months (i.e., current month or the preceding two months).

I manage to calculate the active users for the current month, like this:

```
SELECT 
      EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM createdOn) AS order_createdOn_ym
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT customerId) AS mau
FROM testdata
GROUP BY order_createdOn_ym
ORDER BY order_createdOn_ym asc
;
```

(Fiddle over [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/asPbRETMDqFh1qWoBTcR4B/4).)

However, I'm completely stumped as to how you can approach calculating the 3-months-active users.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: @Strawberry, like for the 1m-active users: a list of months and number of 3m-active users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
select c.createdmonth, count(distinct customerid) as mau
from (
    select distinct date_format(createdon, '%Y-%m-01') as createdmonth
    from testdata
) c
left join testdata t 
    on  t.createdon >= c.createdmonth - interval 2 month
    and t.createdon <  c.createdmonth + interval 1 month
group by c.createdmonth
```

The idea is to enumerate the distinct months, then bring the table with a `left join` that recovers the last 2 month and the current month. You can then aggregate and count the number of distinct customers per group.

Comment: thanks, this seems to be doing the job. Never seen the ON clause used like that though. I need to read up on that...

Comment: for future reference: "non equi join" is the keyword here, and here are good introductions: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-non-equi-join.php, https://www.essentialsql.com/non-equi-join-sql-purpose

Comment: Hats off, @GMB, this is a very slick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@GMB for providing the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64978496/7746472). Purely as a matter of taste I prefer to have the month interval the following way though:

```
SELECT date_format(c.end_of_createdOn_month, '%Y-%m') as order_month, 
       count(distinct customerid) as mau_3m
FROM (
    select distinct LAST_DAY(createdOn) as end_of_createdOn_month
    from testdata
) c
LEFT JOIN testdata t 
    ON  t.createdon >= (c.end_of_createdOn_month - interval 3 month)
    AND t.createdon <=  c.end_of_createdOn_month
GROUP BY c.end_of_createdOn_month;
```